# Quote escaping struggle with grep and sed

Tags: shell, sed, grep, quoting

I'm writing a bash script to extract data from html tags and I found this command in another thread : `grep -o '<tr>.*</tr>' HTMLFILE | sed 's/\(<tr>\|<\/tr>\)//g' > NEWFILE`, it's working great.

But know I want to extract a name from a link in an `<a>` tag, like `<a href="www.mywebsite.com?name="What_I_Want_To_Extract">`.
I thought hard but didn't manage to adapt the command below, any help ?

Comment: Using a proper HTML parser will give you a more robust solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -oP 'name="\K[^"]*' filename`

Output:

`What_I_Want_To_Extract`

See: http://www.charlestonsw.com/perl-regular-expression-k-trick/

Your version adapted:

`grep -o 'name=".*">' HTMLFILE | sed 's/name="\|">//g' NEWFILE`

Comment: so you can test above  echo '<a href="fred.php" name="my file">' | grep -oP 'name="\K[^"]*'

Comment: Thanks it does the trick, what should I add to this command if I want to specify what should come after "What_I_Want_To_Extract", as a class attribute so I restrict my extraction to a <a> with the attribute like class="something" just after the href ?